# SQL Server 2014 change multiple string rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have below data and it will have multiple titles against multiple genres. Every genre has 7 top titles.

```
Genre | MarketingTitle 
------+----------------
Drama | Drama 1
Drama | Drama 2
...
Drama | Drama 7
```

I want output to look something like

```
Genre  | Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | ... | Title7
-------+---------+---------+---------+-----+---------
Drama  | Drama1  | Drama2  | Drama3  | ... | Drama7
Comedy | Comedy1 | Comedy2 | Comedy3 | ... | Comedy7
```

I tried pivot table but its just not working

```
Select 
    GenreName, [Drama], [Comedy]
from
    (select 
         g.name as GenreName, p.MarketingTitle as MarketingTitle
     from 
         programme p
     inner join 
         Genre g on g.Id = p.GenreId
     where 
         topTitle = 1) c
pivot 
    (max(MarketingTitle) 
        for MarketingTitle in ([Drama], [Comedy])
    ) As pvt
```

Everything is returned as null and I am pretty sure this query is wrong.

Even below output is desirable but I cant seem to make query work. any help is appreciated.

```
Drama   | Comedy  | ... | otherGenres
--------+---------+-----+------------
drama1  | comedy1 | ... |
drama2  | comedy2 | ... |
.. .
drama7  | comedy7 | ... |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditional aggregation instead

```
select
    GenreName, Title1 = max(case when rn = 1 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title2 = max(case when rn = 2 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title3 = max(case when rn = 3 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title4 = max(case when rn = 4 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title5 = max(case when rn = 5 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title6 = max(case when rn = 6 then MarketingTitle end)
    , Title7 = max(case when rn = 7 then MarketingTitle end)
from (
    select g.name as GenreName, p.MarketingTitle as MarketingTitle
        , rn = row_number() over (partition by g.name order by p.MarketingTitle)
    from programme p
    inner join Genre g on g.Id = p.GenreId
    where top = 1
) t
group by GenreName
```